# How to force System.Text.Json to say WHICH parameter fails in classic exception "Each parameter in the deserialization constructor..."?

Tags: c#, deserialization, system.text.json

[With System.Text.Json and .Net 6, 7 or higher]

The question is simple: Whenever a deserialization fails because of classic error `Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type '...' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization.` , **how to make it say which parameter was faulty or missing?**

I'm not going to post any code because you might be tempted to tell me yourself which of the parameters is bad. Or you might be tempted to tell me to use a parameter-less constructor. that's what happens every single time this error is mentioned in other questions.

I'm not interested in that. I only want to know *the method* to know more about what caused the problem.

If it helps, I have my own CosmosSerializer class which looks almost exactly like this (that was a pre-requisite for me to be able to use System.Text.Json), but don't let it distract you : https://ankitvijay.net/2021/06/20/custom-json-serializer-settings-with-cosmos-db-sdk/

Comment: The exception is thrown [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Json/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Object/ObjectWithParameterizedConstructorConverter.cs,572) and from the looks of it at that spot there isn't any detail directly available that would help you in determining the problem.

Comment: That is so irritating!

Comment: "you might be tempted" , please don't worry about this. if you have your own serializer, you should have the code that throws exceptions

Comment: @serge except the issue is the same with the default serializer, and except @ ralf showed that it is inside .Net's code with no possibility of getting more details. But thanks anyways.

Comment: I created this in their bug tracker: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/88048